# Is it possible to use WiFi routers provided location in PC?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, geolocation

I am using broadband connection and my ISP’s location is about 15KM away from my home.

Whenever I use some any map app to detect my current location it I think—not sure—it detects the location of my ISP’s physical which is far away from my actual location.

My DSL cable is connected to a WiFi router and from router PC is connected using another network cable. The router provides a very accurate location if I use Wi-Fi using mobile or any devices.

Can I use that location in my computer as well?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not your router that provides the location, it's your IP address. You must be using a shared IP, and because reverse location searches can only have one location, it goes to your ISP's.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Thanks for your information. And yes, it's a shared IP. Is there any possibilities to achieve my goal?

Answer (score -3):

May be you apps are using your phone/tablet GPS.
Your PC took location from your IP. Have a look to this [geolocation ip answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1996129/4068129)